# How to re-write tensorflows tf.reduce_sum in python using linear algebra operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I'm trying to rewrite the operation tf.reduce_sum operation for

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.kernel), [0,1,2], keepdims=False)
```

To use basic linear algebra operations only. The context for doing this is because I'm trying to convert the model to tensorrt which currently doesn't support the reduce_sum operation.

Since the reduce_sum operator is pretty much just a linear operation, there should be a way to write it using much more basic operations. Unfortunately i;m not skilled enough in linear algebra or tensorflow to do this myself and hope to get some help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with NumPy?

Comment: if its possible to be done in numpy its also possible to include it in the tf graph, so yes, doing it in numpy would also help

Answer (score 0):

result = numpy.sum(square_output_tensor.numpy(), axis=(0,1,2), keepdims=False)

This assumes you are working in Eager Mode, otherwise the method call .numpy() will not work.  Instead for Graph Mode you would use tf.py_func instead.

Comment: Also, I am new to Stack Overflow and am looking for initial points.  If this answers your question, please upvote and mark as the accepted answer.  Thank you

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this isn't helpful. Eager Mode is tensorflow 2 I assume, I'm still on tensorflow 1, and the end goal is to transfer it into a tensorrt model, so this definitely won't work. I was hoping for something more primitive like a matrix multiplication or something